# Dependence of the energy levels of a nucleus on its mass number

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why are the energy levels of a heavy nucleus more closely spaced than those of a lighter nucleus? How can we understand this either physically or from the elementary nuclear models?

Answer (score 1):

Think of each energy eigenstate as a standing wave as the nucleus vibrates. Those vibrations might be single-nucleon, few-nucleon, or collective vibrations, or superpositions of the same.

In general, a system with more degrees of freedom has more unique modes of oscillation. Compare the spectrum of standing waves allowed for air in a pipe, versus the spectrum of standing waves for air in the human vocal tract. You can make more different sounds than a pipe, because your vocal tract has degrees of freedom that a pipe doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that heavy atoms has more energy levels variations, due to bigger proton amount in a nucleus. Hence energy levels must be more densely packed to "fit them all on the same table".